# Subaru Blitzen overheating but heater blows cold air

Tags: subaru, overheating, hvac, legacy

I have a 2000 Blitzen.

My heater blows cold air and tonight it overheated.

It is not losing water. Would this be the thermostat or an air blockage?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This could be caused by a number of things, including what you have suggested. No heat, overheating but not loosing coolant would lead me to believe the coolant may be empty or very low. Please use the [edit] feature to add more details about what the coolant level is (once it has cooled down) and what the condition of the coolant is (appearance). Additional information about the vehicle is also helpful; any warning lights, codes, odometer, was this sudden or coming on gradually, etc.

Comment: No warning lights yet.my mum gave it to me 4 weeks ago and the heater wasn't working jus blowing cold air.the mechanic who worked said something about the hot wasn't flowing.tonight was the first time the needle on the temperature gauge went over half way.as soon as it got over half it raised rapidly to hot.

Comment: Coolant levels were empty.

Answer (score 1):

Low coolant can cause there to be no cabin heat because the coolant is not able to be circulated thru the heater core. I am surprised the mechanic did not check the coolant level.

Obviously, when the coolant level gets low enough (empty in your case) it can not be circulated thru the system properly, causing the engine to overheat.

The system will need to be filled properly and air bled. It would also be a great idea to have the cooling system pressure tested to ensure there are no leaks and it is working properly.

After the cooling system is working properly, if you still do not have heat, then it is possible the heater core is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Cold air indicates no coolant. You *might* have a simple problem of a leaking coolant bottle or broken radiator. You *may* have the dreaded Subaru Head Gasket issue. I'd get a sniff test done, to see if the coolant is getting into the engine, and a pressure test to see if the cylinders are all around the same pressure.

Do you have a Turbo, or is it the NA engine? Turbos are much less susceptible to head gasket failure than the NA engine (because of the way the block is forged). 
How many miles on the car? If it has over 105,000miles (169,000km), the timing belt is due for replacement (plus a lot of other work).

If you decide to change the thermostat, buy from a Subaru dealer. Regardless of what the car spares shops tell you, their versions just don't work - the Subaru thermostat is physically slightly longer, and you won't then get any strange overheating issues. And, oddly enough, the Subaru thermostat is usually cheaper than a spares company part.

Comment: It's a twin turbo.done 200.000kms.

Comment: OK - as it's a turbo, they don't suffer as badly from the Subaru head-gasket issues - I'd be looking at the water pump and thermostat. To replace the water pump, the timing belt has to come off, so it's a good time to change that - your mechanic should be able to check if it needs replacing, though. The pump isn't expensive, but the labour is - sorry!